# Printing byte array filled from bytearrayoutputstream

Tags: java, arrays, bytearrayoutputstream

I have filled a byte array using ByteArrayOutputStream. When I print it, the output is confusing. I need some guidance.

Here is my code:

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream bout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(bout);
    try {
        out.writeInt(150);
        byte[] b = bout.toByteArray();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(b));

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Here is my output:

```
[0, 0, 0, -106]
```

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

150 equals to 1001 0110 
which is in term of byte's bits -128 (the left most bit) plus 2 + 4 + 16
= -106

Answer (score 0):

You write the `int` 150 to `out`. In binary (specifically, [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement)), this integer looks like this:

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1001 0110
```

Each group of 8 bits is one byte of data, analogous to the `byte` data type. However, as with all of Java's integer types (except `char`), `byte` is signed. Therefore, even though the last `byte` would have a binary value of `1001 0110`, it displays as `-106`, which is the correct value of that byte in two's complement. You can replace your print statement with:

```
String[] strings = new String[b.length];
for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
    strings[i] = Integer.toString(Byte.toUnsignedInt(b[i]));
}
System.out.println("[" + String.join(", ", strings) + "]");
```

Which will print the bytes in an unsigned format; each one will lie in the  range [0, 255].